# Is there a way to create a new XCode Project using the Command Line?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, command-line, terminal

I was wondering if there is a way to programmatically create a new XCode Project for an iPhone, iPad etc using the Command Line / Terminal?

I found this tool `xcodebuild` [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html) but it only seems to build the App (i.e compile it).  I'm looking for more of a creation prompt to initially set-up the project.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm curious why would you want to do that?

Comment: I really wish I could give more details, because I think it's pretty cool / unique what I'm building for a client, but I signed a pretty strict NDA with this client.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might give you some insights: [Creating an iPhone App "From Scratch"](http://lambdadevp.blogspot.com/2010/11/creating-iphone-app-from-scratch.html)

Comment: Not exactly what I was originally searching for, but this gives me a better idea for how to approach my problem.  Thanks!